Django template rendering order... - problem with include and partial and blocks
I've got:
ViewChild.html:
 {% extends 'app1/parent.html' %}  
 {%block  title%}
        my title
 {%endblock title%} 

Then I've got Parent.html:
{%include 'html_parts/modal_part.html'   %}

That uses partial view:
   {%block  title%} 
     {%endblock  title%}  

Unfortunately, the view is not rendered correctly ie. 'my title' is not displayed.
(it is all ok with application, paths, etc. All files are placed in coorect folders).
It is only something with the logic of rendering. Possibly, I can't use in parent view a partial, that defines block, that is going to be filled by child view?
Any advices?

The reason why "my title" is not being displayed is because of how include works. From the documentation: include "loads a template and renders it with the current context."
This is different from how block works in template inheritance: block tells "the template engine that a child template may override those portions of the template." (Documentation)
What this means in your case is that you would need to update Parent.html to remove {% include 'html_parts/modal_part.html' %} and add {%block title %}, which allows ViewChild.html to override the value of title`.

Ok thanks a lot for the explanation. Do you have any idea, how to achieve what I want, ie - if I've got couple of different parent views (separate ones for : deleting objects, for updating, creating, and all of them are different), but still all of them can use some components that I'd like to have defined in partials - is it achievable?

Rather than having different parent views for different functions, you could have one parent view with the common elements and have different child views for the different functions like creating, deleting or updating objects. For instance, in addition to {% block title %}, you could have {% block content %}, the value of which would change depending on the child view that's being rendered.

You could also change your template calls from blocks to include for parent.html or whichever page and then use with variables. I.e. include ...parent.html with var=123 it sounds like you can/should change your template structure around but there are other options if wanted
